# Automatically convert css to mozilla specific css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If my css is:

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
```

is there a JavaScript library that will convert it to

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
```

automatically if it detects a user agent that is a mozilla browser, example: Firefox?

Comment: Can you not just specify them both in your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add all webkit and mozilla border declarations and be done with it.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
```

http://border-radius.com/

Comment: Because having the css 3 times larger than it needs to be is icky.

Comment: Expanding one declaration won't break the bank for such a trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

With [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) you can use mixins which set browser specific rules automatically.
[This](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/css3/border_radius/) is what you probably need.

There is also another similar library - [Less](http://lesscss.org/), but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) a look.

Comment: Eh? How is this relevant? Modernizr detects support, not which version of the property is supported. And even then, aren't you still going to need to specify the `-moz` version?

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant either.

Answer (score 1):

This is isn't a JavaScript solution, but [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) can achieve this through use of 'functions'.  LESS CSS works using either Ruby, ASP or PHP.

Soon, you will be able to use LESS with JavaScript.  See [less.js](http://github.com/cloudhead/less.js) for info.  Apparently this will form LESS 2.0

First define your function:

```
@border-radius(@radius:10px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
}
```

Then reference it:

E.g.

```
#some-id {
  @border-radius;
}
```

or

```
#some-id {
  @border-radius(210px);
}
```